# Using Python bleach library with Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, tinymce-4

I am looking to sanitize (remove all javascript for example) tinymce generated html code. This code will be rendered within a div on a page and the attempt is to remove all malicious code at the time of saving the tinymce generated code.

The Python [bleach](https://github.com/jsocol/bleach) library seems to be the recommended route to take. Bleach is not present in the Google Appengine supported [thirdparty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) libraries.

Does it mean that I have to install it along with my Python code to Google App Engine ?

Any suggestion for a better implementation is also welcomed.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any third party library not provided by the SDK, needs to be installed in your own project and deployed with your code.

See SDK Pure Python section of the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Pure_Python

SO you will need to install html5lib-python as well as bleach directly in your project.